# Can clients on the android WiFi Hotspot see each other?

Tags: android

I'm going to try and play around with sockets on Java, and I want to know if the clients are going to be able to connect to each other.

Does anyone know?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can connect to each other.

I just tried this with an Android 2.2 device (hotspot) and two other connected devices. They were able to communicate over TCP.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try it later.

Answer (score 0):

Many public wifi hotspots are running in `client isolation mode`. The purpose of this mode is that connected clients cannot see each other.